# Create a small configuration panel inside UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I need to create a small `UITableView` with cells that each contain a `UISwitch`.

For example I want to have two `UISwitch`s, "A" and "B", at rows 0 and 1, so that if I set switch "A" to On, switch "B" will go to the Off position.

How I can do that simply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom table view cells.
Look here for [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.

Use this to detect the changes in switch.

```
[switch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Similar post is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322754/uiswitch-inside-custom-uitableviewcell-not-available)

Comment: Yes,at understand but it's not answer my qusetion... I have already customs table view cells but when I change the value (switch) of the first cell it nee to change the value of the second cell too...I just need to understand the logic steps...

Answer (score 0):

First tag the switches:

```
UISwitch *switchA = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
[switchA addTarget:self action:@selector(actionSwitch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
switchA.tag = 1;

UISwitch *switchB = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
switchB.tag = 2;
```

Then implement the actionSwitch selector:

```
-(void)actionSwitch {

    UISwitch *switchA = (UISwitch)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    UISwitch *switchB = (UISwitch)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
    if([switchA isOn]) {

        [switchB setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```